# Does even a single g++ flag warn about nullpointer dereferencing?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-flags

I wanted to check whether a g++ compiler-flag exists that warns me about nullpointer-dereferencing. When compiling this code with `g++ (GCC) 13.1.1` and these compiler flags: **-Wnull-dereference**, **-Wnonnull**, still nothing happens. No warning, no error..

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  double *elem = new (std::nothrow) double;
  elem = nullptr;
  std::cout << *elem << '\n';

  delete elem;
  return 0;
}
```

So I tried options that control `static analysis`: I only came across these two: **-Wanalyzer-null-argument**, **-Wanalyzer-null-dereference** (still, no success). Is there really no way of achieving this? Note that I am aware of **clang-tidy** and other static analysis tools like ***cpplint, clazy and cppcheck*** that successfully report these kinds of problems. But I want to rely only on compilation flags.

Comment: Most folks write `int main()’. There’s no need for all those decorations, and they get in the way.

Comment: IMPORTANT: the static analyser and flags only finds the nullptr dereferencing that can be detected at compile time. The optimizer flags in the answers below only help the compiler to do constant propagation and find those obvious indirect cases, i.e. where nullptr is used for sure. This does of course not protect against accidental nullptr at runtime which is not related to intiailization (e.g. unsuccessful no-throw allocation) or predictable computations

Comment: @Christophe That's a good point! Thanks for the addition.

Comment: And an example:  https://godbolt.org/z/sfcP94KzY   ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the documentation of `-Wnull-dereference`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wnull-dereference):

> This option is only active when -fdelete-null-pointer-checks is active, which is enabled by optimizations in most targets. The precision of the warnings depends on the optimization options used.

Enable optimizations (`-O1` is enough) and you will get the warning.

`-Wnonnull` does something completely different. (Also see documentation link above.)

The `-Wanalyzer-*` options only take effect if you enable the static anaylzer with `-fanalyzer` and then they are the default. These options are meant to be used in the `-Wno-*` form to disable specific static analyzer checks. See [documentation as well](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.1.0/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there really no way of achieving this?

There is, by enabling optimizations as shown [below](https://godbolt.org/z/13j5sWd7b):

```
-O3 -Wnull-dereference
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/13j5sWd7b)

As you can see using the optimization flag, you get the desired warning.